# Null comparison not working with jenkins groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a small code snippet here

```
                            pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
                            def dataModelVersion = "${pom.properties['data-model.version']}"
                            def item = [("${pom.artifactId}"): "${dataModelVersion}"]
                            if(dataModelVersion!=null){
                                theMap.putAll(item)
                            }
```

Not every pom has a data-model.version value, so it seems like dataModelVersion should contain null which it appears to when I check my map, but for some reason everything is added to the map with that condition, if I change it to dataModelVersion==null to see if I can at least get all null values added nothing gets added

the map will then contain items like

```
vessel-dataset: null
vessel-storage: 0.1.18
simulation: null
```

What am I missing here, I feel like I've tried everything

Comment: "null" is a string, null is the absence of a value. It's wrong to test null for equality. null != null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are assigning to a `dataModelVersion` String (GString) in this line:

```
def dataModelVersion = "${pom.properties['data-model.version']}"
```

and if `pom.properties['data-model.version']` returns `null`

then `dataModelVersion == "null"`

---

so just change it

```
def dataModelVersion = pom.properties['data-model.version']
```